# Postgresql Create Timeframe Using One Column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a yearmonth column which outputs:

SELECT yearmonth
FROM table_1

| yearmonth |
| --- |
| 202201 |
| 202202 |
| 202203 |
| 202204 |
| 202205 |

I would need to create some sort of output that selects the last 6 months per yearmonth. So the desired output would look like:

| period | yearmonth |
| --- | --- |
| 202201 | 202201 |
| 202201 | 202112 |
| 202201 | 202111 |
| 202201 | 202110 |
| 202201 | 202109 |
| 202201 | 202108 |
| 202202 | 202202 |
| 202202 | 202201 |
| 202202 | 202112 |
| 202202 | 202111 |
| 202202 | 202110 |
| 202202 | 202109 |

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a CTE subquery to get your table_1 data and then `generate_series()` to create a series of dates.

With test data as:

```
create table table_1 as
select unnest(array[202201, 202202, 202203, 202204, 202205 ]) as yearmonth;
```

Query:

```
with months as 
(select yearmonth::text, yearmonth::text || '01' as yearmonthday from table_1)
select 
    months.yearmonth, 
    generate_series(months.yearmonthday::date - '6 months'::interval , months.yearmonthday::date, '1 month'::interval)
from months;
```

Note that your date format YYYYMM does not parse correctly, so I have appended '01' to make the date format YYYYMMDD as "yearmonthday".

Produces the following:

| yearmonth | generate_series |
| --- | --- |
| 202201 | 2021-07-01 00:00:00 |
| 202201 | 2021-08-01 00:00:00 |
| 202201 | 2021-09-01 00:00:00 |
| 202201 | 2021-10-01 00:00:00 |
| 202201 | 2021-11-01 00:00:00 |
| 202201 | 2021-12-01 00:00:00 |
| 202201 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 202202 | 2021-08-01 00:00:00 |
| 202202 | 2021-09-01 00:00:00 |
| 202202 | 2021-10-01 00:00:00 |
| … |  |

Comment: @hahahahahelp does this answer help solve your problem?